# How to optimize the listview int android?

Tags: android, listview

In my ListView, every item have some TextViews and Images, They defined in the xml layout file.

```
 ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.vw_system_notice_list_item, null);
```

But They are in different types. Some may show Images ,some not. Now I am check in the getView method:

```
if (TextUtil.isEmpty(systemMessage.image)) {
                viewHolder.img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

I'm thinking, I have create some useless ImageView objects, then `setVisibility(View.GONE)`.
How can I optimize the memory or listview ?

Comment: https://speakerdeck.com/cyrilmottier/optimizing-android-ui-pro-tips-for-creating-smooth-and-responsive-apps this is very good example optimized list view

Answer (score 0):

Two solution,

1. This you have already done, like hiding, un hiding based on scenario.
2. This one will require little extra effort.

   a. First make an adapter and use

   getViewTypeCount() :- here you will return the number of different view your list support, like in your case have two seperate layouts one with images and text views, and other without imageview.

   getItemViewType(int position) : - here you will have to check for this particular position what should be the layout of child.

once done, all you need to do is have little extra code in getView method of your adapter.
here is a sample code, which you have to elaborate for yourself, apart then this two, i dont think you have anyother option unless you extend AbsListView and create one for yourself as per your own need.

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the type of view you want for this position
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if(convertView == null)
        switch(type){
          // inflate,populate and return different view types
          // from here
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // Return here number of different views you have
        return super.getViewTypeCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Return here the type of view you want to use, for this position
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}

Atlast just hook this adapter to your list and enjoy !!


for more info, i guess you can see this link  [http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296][1]
```